# data-toggle="dropdown" activates a route redirect instead of a dropdown in yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman

I'm using the [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/), specifically the "Drop-down Datetime with input box". It makes use of the `data-toggle="dropdown"`attribute. The calendar appeared when I had my AngularJS App running on a simple nodejs express server. Since I migrated to yeoman, clicking on the dropdown activates a redirect to `/#` (`http://localhost:9000/#`)

This is how I'm using the datetimepicker in the view:

**dtpform.html**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
        <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="startDate"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="startDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2', minView: 'hour' }"/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Other people that had the same problem forgot some dependencies. Mine seem to be all set. If I insert the datetimepicker into the index.html instead of the /dtp route, it Pops Up.

**index.html**

```
...
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
...
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('c2gyoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'angularMoment',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker'
  ])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      ...
      .when('/dtp', {
        ...
        templateUrl: 'views/dtpform.html',
        ...
      }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/c2g'
    });
  });
  ...
```

Any Ideas what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `href="#"` appear to be the problem. The href tag will be telling the angular router to navigate to the route that matches `/#`. If you remove that, the dropdown should open ok.

Comment: Same result with or without `#`, still getting redirected and the calendar doesn't open.

Comment: I have tried this setup exactly as you have described using angular generator for yeoman. And removing the href whilst its on another route such as `/dtp`, Makes it pop up correctly, where as leaving the href on makes it redirect to `/#` the same as you.

Comment: By mistake I had `dtpform.html` twice in my app in different folders. I was always editing the one that didn't get used, so nothing was changing. Removing the `#` on the right file did fix it.

Comment: This solution worked! Thanks a ton.  But the behaviour started suddenly probably after a bower update. What could be the possible reason? Any idea?